# Что такое уязвимость (vulnerability) в NPM?

Tags: node.js, gulp, npm

Обычно, для новых проектов копирую файл package.json со старых проектов, который содержит только зависимости (названия и версии). После выполнения команды `npm i` выводится сообщение, что есть какие-то уязвимости и их можно исправить командой `npm audit fix`.
Какие тут вообще могут быть уязвимости? Объясните, пожалуйста, новичку.

Answer (score 2):

Посмотрите [bug bounty program](https://hackerone.com/nodejs-ecosystem) в **Node.js third-party modules** или откройте раздел [hacktivity](https://hackerone.com/nodejs-ecosystem/hacktivity?sort_type=latest_disclosable_activity_at&filter=type%3Aall%20to%3Anodejs-ecosystem&page=1), где практически все узвимости имеют статус disclosed, и каждый может посмотреть как работает тот или иной найденный баг, и к какой категории багов он вообще относится: `critical`, `high`, `medium`, `low`, или `none`.

Comment: При установке любого пакета через `npm i <пакет> --save-dev` выдаётся сообщение, что найдены уязвимости (всегда есть со статусом high). Раньше такого не было (установил новую версию). Подскажите, пожалуйста, мне каждый раз прописывать `npm audit fix` или вообще не обращать внимания? P. S. Сами пакеты успешно устанавливаются.

Comment: Если хотите модуль без вулна - прописывайте каждый раз. Безопасность превыше всего. Ну а если хотите дырявый сайт, где любой может на сёрвере выполнить RCE - то не прописывайте.